# SPARQL query for retrieving all object properties about one individual (in Protege)

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege, rdf-xml

I have data for 20 breeds as `individual` and their costs, energy level, adaptability level, hypoallergenic, and the purposes of having them as `object properties`. I want to retrieve all `object properties` in individual.

so far this is my query:

```
PREFIX dog: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/guguk_test.owl#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?dog dog:hasAdaptability ?adaptability .
    ?dog dog:hasCost ?cost .
    ?dog dog:hasEnergy ?energy .
    ?dog dog:hasHypoallergenic ?hypoallergenic .
    ?dog dog:hasPurpose ?purpose .
}
```

the result show all the breeds (`individual`) with all the `object properties`

this is screenshot of the result
[image: screenshot of the result]

I need to select just 1 breed (`individual`) and `object properties` of that breed.

I already try this query but the result was: `no matches found`.

```
PREFIX dog: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/guguk_test.owl#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?dog dog:hasBreeds dog:Basenji .
    ?dog dog:hasAdaptability ?adaptability .
    ?dog dog:hasCost ?cost .
    ?dog dog:hasEnergy ?energy .
    ?dog dog:hasHypoallergenic ?hypoallergenic .
    ?dog dog:hasPurpose ?purpose .
}
```

Comment: We don't know your ontology, so how can we know why the second query doesn't match? Obviously either the property `hasBreeds` is wrong or there is no `dog:Basenji` ...  or maybe one of the other properties has no values for that breed...your see, without the data -> impossible to help!

Comment: Screenshots are often not looked at. If you had provided your results as text, I'm sure @AKSW would have seen what I did.

Comment: ... now that I see the answer of @TallTed ... is there no property `hasBreeds` at all in your ontology? From your small unreadable screenshot, I can`t see how a particular dog is related to a breed...

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
PREFIX dog: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/guguk_test.owl#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
    VALUES ?dog { dog:Basenji } .
    ?dog dog:hasAdaptability ?adaptability .
    ?dog dog:hasCost ?cost .
    ?dog dog:hasEnergy ?energy .
    ?dog dog:hasHypoallergenic ?hypoallergenic .
    ?dog dog:hasPurpose ?purpose .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use variables for properties too. This query will fetch them all, even if you change your ontology :

```
PREFIX dog: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/guguk_test.owl#>

SELECT * WHERE {
    dog:Basenji ?property ?value
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [BIND operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind) to assign the breed you want to retrieve to a variable.

```
PREFIX dog: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/guguk_test.owl#>

SELECT * WHERE {
    BIND (dog:Basenji AS ?dog)

    ?dog ?property ?value
}
```